# pysnmp : Anything wrong in the bottom code?

Tags: pysnmp

**> This Code is not working , Any idea why?

> passing  json object {'vmUserName': 'admin', 'partitionCpuUsage': 3.0}

def sendTrap_gen(self, event, eventvals):

```
     mibViewController = view.MibViewController(self.snmpEngine.getMibBuilder())

     # Create Notification Originator App instance.
     ntfOrg = ntforg.NotificationOriginator()
     ntfOrg.snmpContext = self.snmpContext

     trapName = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity('PARTITION-MIB', event)


     ntfOrg.sendVarBinds(
         self.snmpEngine,
         'my-notification',  # notification targets
         None, '',  # contextEngineId, contextName
         rfc1902.NotificationType( 
             trapName,
             objects={('PARTITION-MIB', k): v for k, v in eventvals.items()}
         ).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)

     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you started the main I/O loop:

```
self.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
```

How your code is different from [this](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/agent/ntforg/common-notifications.html#snmpv2c-trap-via-notification-type) or [this](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/ntforg/snmp-versions.html#snmpv2c-trap) example?

Comment: Actually I am getting "TypeError: resolveWithMib() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)" . on pysnmp 4.4.12. It worked fine on 4.4.4

Comment: This is my MIB entry 
partitionCpuUsageReachedTheThreshold NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS { vmUserName, partitionCpuUsage }
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
      "This notfication for System cpu usage reached the threshold"
    ::= { partitionNotfs 1 }

Comment: can you help me in figuring out how to fix the issue with resolveWithMib(mibViewController)